# Create a foreign key to a table that is not part of the context in Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In our system, we have new tables that are managed with Entity Framework Code First, and legacy tables that are not.

How can I define a foreign key in our Code First model that references a table which is not managed by Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could

1. Write the SQL to generate the foreign key manually. Since EF is not aware of the other table, it does not need to be aware of the actual reference to it.

   **OR**
2. Add an entity that will represent the yet unmanaged table and reference it normally through EF, either by convention, e.g. with navigation properties, or by fluent API.